# Sprite Kit Size Change

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have found this bizarre thing in SpriteKit. When I create a sprite node it has a width and height of 100.
[image: Sprite node has dimensions width: 100 and height: 100, when scene is parent node.]
However when I make that sprite node the child of another node it's width and height change bizarrely.
[image: Sprite node has dimensions width: 14 and height: 12, when sprite is parent node.]

What is this Bizarre behaviour? and how can I prevent it from happening? It has started messing with many of my projects as programmatically created squares become rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sprites scales are thrown out of wack. In reality the Sprite still has a size of 100 x 100 just it doesn't have a scale of 1,1 anymore. I think that this is a bug in Scene editor and I find it mostly occurs if I resize a sprite visually vs typing in size differences. To fix it just change the scales back to 1 and then manually change the size back to what it should be in the Attributes panel

Comment: The problem is that this is affecting all of my projects. If I am to create a square programmatically it becomes a rectangle

Comment: You really shouldn't add or change the scope of your question after it has been answered. It makes answers not as relevant.

Comment: you should create a new question for your oblong programmatically created square issue

Comment: sorry I thought that they were really the same issue.

Comment: Your solution for the Scene editor did not work for me. When I did that it made the sprite a rectangle

Comment: check the scale properties of the parent that you are adding the child to

Comment: Thanks I think that that was the problem